# Flowing Random Items from SQL Database in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

I am trying to put random items from a SQL database into tkinter for Python. However, I keep getting an Invalid Syntax error at value=val).pack(anchor=W)). When I break down the program into two parts (the random items from the database and the tkinter box), they work, but not together. Any suggestions?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S

v = IntVar()
v.set(1)

from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
import time
noogie=3
chimmy = []
import MySQLdb
import random 



db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
                     user="root", 
                      passwd="", 
                      db="antonymes") # name of the day
cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM antonyms ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1;")


for i in range(cur.rowcount):
  row = cur.fetchone()
  print row[1]
  curry = row[2]                     
  chimmy.insert(0, row[2])


cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT antonyme FROM antonyms ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;")  

while noogie <> 0:
 for j in range(cur.rowcount):

  row = cur.fetchone()
  chimmy.insert(1, row)
  noogie=noogie-1
  break



Label(root,
      text=""""Choose the opposite of this word""",
         justify = LEFT,
         padx = 20).pack()

for txt, val in chimmy:
  Radiobutton(root,
              text=txt,
              padx = 20,
              variable=v,
              command=ShowChoice,
              value=val).pack(anchor=W))

master = Tk()
app = App(master)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: At the end of your code you create an instance of `App`, but you never define `App` anywhere. You're also creating a bunch of widgets before creating the root widget. You need to create the root widget first.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have many bugs in your code, your syntax error is caused by this line:

```
value=val).pack(anchor=W))
```

It should be this instead (note that there is only one `)` at the end of the line)

```
value=val).pack(anchor=W)
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I'm still trying to understand the tkinter widget and haven't quite grasped it yet.

Comment: @L2010: this problem has nothing to do with tkinter -- it's a python syntax error.